# Does Cloud Bigtable have a local development server like Cloud Datastore?

Tags: emulation, google-cloud-bigtable

If not, is there any document that list best practices to integration-test an application that uses Cloud Bigtable? Specifically the applications written in Java and Python.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No document, but you might benefit from looking at how the [client integration tests](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-integration-tests/pom.xml) work.

Comment: Thanks for the link @les.

Comment: This recommendation is now out of date, given the recently-released Cloud Bigtable emulator. Please see my recently-added answer for details.

Comment: the URL is dead too

Answer (score 5):

Google Cloud Bigtable team recently released an [in-memory emulator](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator) that you can run locally as part of your development environment. You can use it for both interactive work as well as automated integration tests.